# Pandas Sort Values Not Behaving the Same as Excel Sort

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a small dataframe that I would like to sort in Python. When sorting in Python, I get a different result then when sorting in Excel. I would like to sort from A to Z and have the pandas result match what is outputted in Excel.

Here is the code I used:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Col": ['0123A', '0123B', '01-AB']})
df = df.sort_values('Col', ascending=True)
```

Here is the output in python:

```
     Col
2  01-AB
0  0123A
1  0123B
```

My output in excel is this:

```
     Col
0  0123A
1  0123B
2  01-AB
```

Is there a reason why the pandas and excel result don't match?

Comment: they're treating the dashes differently

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  There is a reason that the pandas sort and the Excel sort are different.  The pandas sort is utilizing an ASCIII/UTF sorting hierarchy, which probably is what you expected; whereas, Excel treats the minus sign/hyphen differently in the sorting process.  If you want the Excel spreadsheet to sort in the same manner as the pandas sort, you need to utilize some additional definitions and processing like what is explained if you connect to this link.

[Excel Hyphen Sorting](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/sorting-a-number-with-dash/m-p/2321087)

You might need to read through the solution a few times for it to register, but sorting columns where cell contents can contain a hyphen requires a bit of extra work in Excel.

I hope that helps.

Regards.